# Laravel 5.2 : touch intended url on login and registeration without middleware

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

There is a page(route) that also has a login/register form inside itself addition to its content.
user is not forced to login to have access to this page . but login to site  would show him more data in the page.
 I am going to redirect  him back to this page if he try to login via the internal login/register form .
I prefer not to use various login class and methods and adhere to `AuthController` .
 so apparently i should change the session `intended` value before preform login/register but how?

*(I know if a user try to access a protected route he will be redirected to login page and then redirected back to intended url.but this is **NOT** my case!)*

Answer (score 0):

you can customize handle method in `authenticate.php` since default protected route using auth middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return redirect()->guest('your/url');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

or you can create another middleware and specify them at `App\Config.php` then register them at `Http\kernel.php`

Comment: I declared that user is not forced to login so route is not an `auth` protected route thus authenticate middleware will not fire

Comment: i'm little bit confused of your case. you said user is not forced to login but by login they can see more data on that page. another scenario, if user try to login via internal page, he will be redirected to the page you intended to. do you wish token based authentication or something? if you want to change `intended` session, i think you can put an url `return redirect()->intended('your/url')` . take a look at redirector.php file. i don't know if it helps you out